# What is the polar of an Euclidean unit ball but its center is not in the origin

Tags: analytic-geometry

I know that the polar of an Euclidean unit ball is itself, but I wonder what if its center is not in the origin, like:
$$
B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \mid(x-1)^2+y^2\le1\}
$$
and the polar of a set is: 
$$ B^{\circ} = \{ c \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \langle c,x \rangle \leq 1 \quad \forall x \in B  \} $$
Please show me some details, thank a lot!!

Comment: Let $x = 1 + \cos(t)$, you figure out the reset.

Comment: so it's (x+1)^2+y^2<=1~~ a little weird~~